# SQL date formatting to show numeric date value followed by a suffix

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

I want to write a query that will display today's date in this format " **October 7th of year 2020** " So I wrote this query

`SELECT  TO_CHAR(sysdate,'Month DdTH "of year" YYYY') as "next day" from dual`

but the output shows me October **07th** of year 2020. Is there any way for me to not show the 0 before 7th?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'fmMonth dTH "of year" YYYY') as "next day" 
FROM dual
```

The single `dTH` does what you want for that component.  The leading `fm` removes the padding on the month.

You can see the results [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1ef3b233e9fcf952eba2bcdeeb60f642).

Answer (score 1):

Sure. `FM`

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(sysdate,'Month fmDdTH "of year" YYYY') as "next day" from dual
                               ^^
                               this
```